# SVG 100% Width Height Round Caps

Tags: svg

I want to have my SVG, that is 100% width and height, with round caps.
Now they are kinda stretched.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: cadetblue
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 20px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <path d="M15 15 L85 15 L85 85 L15 85 L15 50 L50 50 " class="st0"/>
        </svg>
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it myself:
Just added

```
vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
```

Into the SVG